# Get percentage between two dates as a float in Swift

Tags: swift, date

So I'm currently trying to add a feature that given two dates, will tell me how far through I am.

**TLDR:**
So, let's say I have a date that is `July 1st, 2017 20:00:00` and another that is `July 2nd, 2017 22:00:00` and today is `July 2nd, 08:00:00`, then I will get that I am 46.17% of the way through.

The way I tried to do this is using a simple formula:

> progress = (current time - start time) / (end time - start time)

but when put into code, I can subtract two dates, and get the `DateComponent` difference, but I cannot divide two `DateComponent`'s. Here is my code set up, with an extension t

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-01 20:00:00")
let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-02 22:00:00")
let currentDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-01 08:00:00")

let progress = (currentDate - startDate) / (endDate - startDate)



extension Date {
    static func - (date1: Date, date2: Date) -> DateComponents {
        let calender:Calendar = Calendar.current
        return calender.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date1, to: date2)
    }
}
```

There has to be a way around dividing two dates. I can't think of it though, everything I find online (using different languages) has required division between two dates.

I tried to convert everything to seconds and just divide that, but I didn't know what to do with the seconds to convert them back to a `DateComponent` because there might be a 5000 second difference. Any help appreciated!

Comment: calculate the distance in minutes (or seconds or hours, etc...) between the _start_ and the _end_ date, then do the same thing between the _start_ and the _middle_ date; then you have everything to get the current percentage by a simple division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to turn the dates into numbers, because then you can add and subtract them.

You can use the `timeIntervalSince1970` to turn the date into numbers, then you can use your formula:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-01 20:00:00")!.timeIntervalSince1970
let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-02 22:00:00")!.timeIntervalSince1970
let currentDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-02 08:00:00")!.timeIntervalSince1970

let percentage = (currentDate - startDate) / (endDate - startDate)
```

Alternatively, use `timeIntervalSince(_:)`:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-01 20:00:00")!
let duration = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-02 22:00:00")!.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
let elapsed = formatter.date(from: "2017-07-02 08:00:00")!.timeIntervalSince(startDate)

let percentage = elapsed / duration
```

I think this way is better because you get less maths :).

Comment: `endDate` and `currentDate` are badly named in the second code snippet. They're not dates, they're time intervals.

Comment: @Alexander Oh I didn't realise! Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`:

```
let currentInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let startInterval = startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let endInterval = endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let progress = ((currentInterval - startInterval) / (endInterval - startInterval)) * 100
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1417376-timeintervalsincereferencedate) is apples documentation on it. Basically it returns the amount of seconds that have passed since the reference date of January 1, 2001 UTC.

Comment: Oh wow, and here I was just about to convert everything to seconds and back myself. Thanks a million!

Comment: Take a look at Sweeper's answer. He simplified the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do the exact same calculation, just convert `startdate`, `enddate`, and `currentdate` into milliseconds using `yourDate.timeIntervalSince1970`

That should give you a decimal between 0 and 1, and just multiply by 100 for the percentage